# Why `.and` behaves different than `.where` in Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

Given the following setup

```
vehicle_table = Vehicle.arel_table
make_column = vehicle_table[:make]
model_column = vehicle_table[:model]
```

Why does

```
Vehicle.where(make_column.matches('Tesla')).and(model_column.matches('S'))
```

Results in

```
SELECT "vehicles".* FROM "vehicles" WHERE "vehicles"."model" LIKE 'S'
```

While this

```
Vehicle.where(make_column.matches('Tesla')).where(model_column.matches('S'))
```

Successfully results in the expected behavior?

```
SELECT 1 AS one FROM "vehicles" WHERE "vehicles"."model" LIKE 'S' AND "vehicles"."make" LIKE 'Tesla' LIMIT ?
```

Comment: I'm surprised `and` works in your example, according to API, it should accept relation as an argument, but you provide arel node instead. What `Vehicle.where(make_column.matches('Tesla')).and(Vehicle.where(model_column.matches('S')))` returns?

Comment: @mikdiet I'm also really suprised as it should be raising "You have passed Arel::Nodes::Matches object to #and. Pass an ActiveRecord::Relation object instead.". What version of Rails is this and just WHY? https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/de53ba56cab69fb9707785a397a59ac4aaee9d6f/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L828